# how to get values from button using touches began function in swift.?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get values from touches began and touches move. I have this code but this is only use for moving not getting value.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

    if touch.view == btn1 {
        println("touchesMoved")
    } else {
        println("touchesMoved This is not an ImageView")
    } 
}
```

Comment: By values what you mean ?button image or text ?

Comment: yes button value.i want to use these functions and get value from button

Comment: Which value? You can already get any data by btn1 object.

Comment: i have a buton i give him value and i want to show his value in a label using these functions brother

Comment: How you give value to button in titleLabel or tag?

Comment: you will not get Button value from `touchesBegan` method. you need to create your own methods for all buttons inside that views. you can only use this methods for views except buttons

Comment: okay brother thnx Jigar Tarsariya and santak brother

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.view == self.button {
            // Do whatever
            // get button tag => button.tag
            // get button titleLabel => button.titleLabel.text
            // get button image => button.imageView.image

        } else {
            return
        }   
    }
}
```

Use this.